# How to use metaphors and similes in a good dose?

Tags: metaphor

If you know me well, you will know that I use *too* many metaphors and similes. Everybody, keeps telling me to tone it down, but when I try, I tone it down too much. Is there a way to use metaphors and similes in a good dose(Not too many, but not too less)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similes are like a fine wine, best savored slowly but consistently. Metaphors are bulldozers. They will help move your work for you but they are big and too many can get in the way of each other.

But in all seriousness, try treating it with metrics. If the feedback you are receiving is that you have too many, try removing ten percent. See how that goes over. Maybe you need twenty percent reduction? Once you do this a few times you will get a feel for how often to use them. Also try removing different ones for different readers and see if it is just certain uses that are actually bothering them.